# Can not exit from node app, when using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-container

`CRT + C` is not stopping the node app, when I run the app using docker. Following are the steps I have done. I would be very thankful for your help.

My node app.

```
var config  = require('./config.json');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var request = require('request');
var http    = require('http');

// Debug log entry when starting the daemon.
console.log("REST daemon started successfully.\n");
console.log("The daemon interval is : "+ config.queue_interval +".\n");


// Resetting failed REST calls if there are any.
if (config.reset_when_start) resetCallbacks();

// Calling processQueue with the given interval.
setInterval(setSubDaemon, config.queue_interval);
setSubDaemon();

function setSubDaemon() {
   // my code is here.
}
```

And my docker command for running the nodeapp is follow.

```
docker run --link mongo:mongo -v /home/eranga/workspace/clms/daemon:/opt -p 127.0.0.1:8087:8080 custom-node-image
```

Answer (score 2):

For node application try to add this in your bootstrap file/file where you start your server listening

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to exit from docker node app, use this below command
CTRL + P + Q

Comment: This leaves the container running in the background